# Composite expressions of the form $a^n +1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I call a diophantine expression $f(n)$ a *composite expression* if $f(n)$ is a composite number for every integer $n$. I am interested in expressions of the form $a^n + 1$. It is trivially seen that such expressions are composite whenever $a$ is odd, or is a perfect odd power. I strongly believe that these are the only cases. Therefore I propose the following:
**Conjecture 1:** The expression $a^n + 1$ is composite if and only if $a$ is odd, or is a perfect odd power.
This is easily seen to be equivalent to the following: 
**Conjecture 1':** If $2a$ is not a perfect odd power, there is a prime of the form $2^{2^{n}}a^{2^{n}} + 1$. 
Could you prove or disprove these conjectures, or at least give me some indication of how this could be done? It seems rather difficult. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Given that we don't know if we have infinitely many Fermat primes out there, or even do we have at least _one more_ of them, your conjecture (which is almost a generalization of that, in a way) seems pretty difficult indeed.

Comment: @IvanNeretin It's different. It asks if $a^n+1$ is composite _for all $n\ge 1$_ if and only if $a$ is odd or is a perfect odd power. So clearly $2^n+1$ is not "composite" (in OP's definition).

Comment: Yes, I see, hence the "almost" in my comment.

Comment: @Daniel With a perfect odd power, do you mean a perfect power of $2$ with odd exponent or a power of an odd number ?

Comment: Is a prime of the form $$\large 18^{2^n}+1$$, $n\ge 1$ known ?

Comment: For $1\le n\le 14$ , $\large 18^{2^n}+1$ is composite.

Comment: @Peter If $a=b^k$ with $k$ odd, then $a^n+1=\left(b^n+1\right)\left(b^{nk-n}-b^{nk-n-1}\pm \cdots -b+1\right)$, which is composite.

Comment: @Peter I mean a perfect power with odd exponent and arbitrary base.

Comment: A solution to this problem is probably out of reach. It is not known, whether there is a generalized fermat prime number for every suitable base. I would tend to think there are bases $b$, such that $\large b^{2^n}+1$ , $n\ge 1$, is never prime, of course with the mentioned restriction.

Comment: @IvanNeretin,@user236182 No number of the form $2^{2^{n}}$ can be a perfect odd power, so if my conjecture is correct there would be for every $n$, an $m$ such that $({2^{2^{n}}})^{2^{m}} + 1 = 2^{2^{n+m}} + 1$ is a prime number. So my conjecture would indeed imply the existence of infinitely many Fermat primes. It is, therefore, a generalization of this statement in the strictest sense of the word.

Comment: @Peter Base $18$ is trivial, $18^1 + 1 = 19$ is prime.

Comment: @Peter I am not aware of any prime of the form $18^{2^{n}} + 1$, with $n \geq 1$, though.

Comment: It is worth remarking that since $a^{2^{n}}$ cannot be an perfect odd power without $a$ being so, it follows from my conjecture that for every base $a$ satisfying my conditions, there must be infinitely many primes of the form $a^n+1$ (or equivalently $a^{2^{n}}+1$).

Comment: It is believed that there are infinite many primes of the form $a^2+1$ , $a^4+1$ , $a^8+1$ , etc. because the polynomials $\large x^{2^n}+1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb Q$. But for a fixed $a$, there are probably only finite many primes of the form $\large a^{2^n}+1$.

Comment: @Daniel I supposed $n\ge 1$, but even if $n=0$ is allowed, there will be examples, where it is difficult to find a prime.

Comment: @Peter Not only there will be such examples, but as I showed above, the two questions are equally difficult, since whenever $a$ satisfies my conditions, $a^{2^{n}}$ also does; in particular, $18^2$ will satisfy them, so my conjecture would imply the existence of a prime of your form.